# Segmentation fault 11?

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, arguments

My program compiles but when I run it `./program -n 3 1000.txt`, I get

> segmentation fault: 11.

What does it mean?

What my program does: print the first 10 lines of the file. If the file has less than 10 lines the entire file should be printed. The program should not create any files. It just prints part of the content of a file to standard output.

It should also be possible to specify that a different number of lines be printed. This will specified by passing the string `-n` as the first argument to the program, the number of lines to be printed as the second argument and the file as the third argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

int i, n;
char line[1024];
n = atoi(argv[2]);

if(argc == 2){ //eg ./program 1000.txt
    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("1000.txt", "r");
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        fgets(line, 1024, fPointer);
        fprintf(fPointer, "%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(fPointer);
} else if(argc == 4){ //eg ./program -n 4 1000.txt
    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("1000.txt", "r");
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        fgets(line, 1024, fPointer);
        fprintf(fPointer, "%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(fPointer);
} else {
    printf("Wrong number of inputs.\n");
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your program did something the OS doesn't like. Are you sure readable `1000.txt` exists in proper path? Adding check if `fopen()` was successful is good.

Comment: It means you are accessing memory that you should not be. Perhaps a null pointer? Use a debugger to find out. PS: Check the manual page for `fopen` and not it may return `null` in the event of the file not being able to be opened

Comment: Use a debugger to help you find the problem. And you really should add error checking in your code. That will make your code more robust and will also help you debug any issues.

Comment: Might be worth looking into [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Comment: Are you using Linux? Just run it on GDB and it will show you where it crashes and why.

Comment: `n = atoi(argv[2]);` is a problem if `argc` is `2`. You need to move that inside the block under `if ( argc == 4)`.

Comment: Why not start the code with `if (argc != 4) return 1;` to validate you have your arguments before you start assigning them. You also avoid nesting the remainder of your code. (you can also print an error within the `if` block regarding `insufficient input`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Because `argc == 2` should be also allowed?

Comment: Changed fprintf(fPointer, "%s\n", line) to printf("%s", line); because we are only reading the file as pointed out by @Yağmur Oymak.

Comment: Also moved the n=atoi(argv[2]); to inside the if(argc == 4) function because leaving it outside would change argv[2] for the argc=2 function too. Suggested by @RSahu, and Programmer 400 below.

Result: success! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fprintf(fPointer, "%s\n", line)
```

This is the problem. You are getting a line by `fgets` into your array, and instead of printing it to standard output, you try to print to the file which you have opened read-only. You just need to use normal `printf` for that job.

**EDIT**

It turned out it is not the reason why it `segfaults`, but it still is a problem if you want your program do what you want.

Check if the file really exists, that may be the problem as pointed out by @MikeCAT.

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't read the specification enough to determine this causes *undefined behavior* or not, but the program didn't throw Segmentation Fault in [my experiment](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ezRV6leU8z64EPCZ).

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes, you are right. I thought that was the problem. However it worked on my computer but did not write anything anywhere.  Interesting, I will edit my answer when  I find something relevant.

Comment: I can not get it to segfault without using wrong number of arguments and it only segfaults in 'n = atoi(argv[2]);'. Sorry for posting an answer without cheking.

Comment: I got Segmentation Fault when [I removed the file](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eNjeoOwnxpyiExet).

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes, I also tried and got a segfault. Should I edit my answer to include this, or will you post an answer?

Answer (score 4):

This example will print 3 lines of the file for the arguments `$ ./a.out -n 3 data.txt`. I moved the `atoint` inside the condition and I changed the printing to `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, n;
    char line[1024];
    FILE *fPointer;
    if (argc == 2) { //eg ./program 1000.txt
        FILE *fPointer;
        fPointer = fopen("data.txt", "r");
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            fgets(line, 1024, fPointer);
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        fclose(fPointer);
    } else if (argc == 4) { //eg ./program -n 4 1000.txt
        n = atoi(argv[2]);
        FILE *fPointer;
        fPointer = fopen("data.txt", "r");
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fgets(line, 1024, fPointer);
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        fclose(fPointer);
    } else {
        printf("Wrong number of inputs.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

File data.txt

```
Superman
Batman
Cyclops
Thor
Wolverine
Superman
Batman
Cyclops
Thor
Wolverine
Superman
Batman
Cyclops
Thor
Wolverine
Superman
Batman
Cyclops
Thor
Wolverine
```

Output

```
$ ./a.out -n 3 data.txt
Superman

Batman

Cyclops
```